# Curious issue with Oracle UNION and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-order-by, union-all

The following query is [perfectly valid](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/34078) in pretty much every database (give or take a `dual` dummy table), including Oracle:

```
select 'A' as x from dual union all
select 'B'      from dual
order by x asc
```

Returning:

```
| X |
|---|
| A |
| B |
```

Now this query is still quite standard SQL, but [doesn't work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/34079) on Oracle

```
select 'A' as x from dual union all
select 'B'      from dual union all
select 'C'      from dual
order by x asc
```

I'm getting

```
ORA-00904: "X": invalid identifier
```

This, however, [works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/34080):

```
select 'A' as x from dual union all
select 'B' as x from dual union all
select 'C'      from dual
order by x asc
```

I've been playing around with this issue and figured out that apparently, at least the first subselect and the *second-last* (??) subselect need to have a column called `x`. In the first example, the two subselects seemed to simply coincide. [Working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/34081):

```
select 'A' as x from dual union all
select 'B'      from dual union all
select 'C'      from dual union all
select 'D'      from dual union all
select 'E'      from dual union all
select 'F' as x from dual union all
select 'G'      from dual
order by x asc
```

As you may have guessed, this [wouldn't work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/34082):

```
select 'A' as x from dual union all
select 'B'      from dual union all
select 'C'      from dual union all
select 'D'      from dual union all
select 'E' as x from dual union all
select 'F'      from dual union all
select 'G'      from dual
order by x asc
```

#### Interesting side-note:

Derived tables seem not to suffer from this limitation. [This works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/34123):

```
select * from (
  select 'A' as x from dual union all
  select 'B'      from dual union all
  select 'C'      from dual
)
order by x asc
```

#### Question:

Is this a (known?) bug in the Oracle SQL parser, or is there any very subtle detail in the language syntax that absolutely requires the first and the second-last subselect to hold a column of the name as referenced from the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: Just to add a little bit to this, in `SQL Server 2008 R2` the first select - column must have the alias on it.

Comment: @Elias: Yes, I've tried with SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and H2 so far.

Comment: Seems to have been raised as bug 14196463 but closed with no resolution. Also mentioned in community thread 3561546. Just for info, reproduced in 11.2.0.3 and 10.2.0.5.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This doesn't really answer the question, but it seems to be a parser bug (or 'feature') rather than a language requirement.

According to My Oracle Support, this seems to have been raised as bug 14196463 but closed with no resolution. It's also mentioned in [community thread 3561546](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3561546). You need a MOS account, or at least an Oracle account, to see either of those though.

It's also been discussed [in an OTN thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2471511) which requires a basic Oracle login rather than a MOS account, as far as I can tell. That also doesn't have much information but repeats your findings, and also suggests the behaviour has existed back at least to 9.2.0.8 and perhaps much earlier.

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries005.htm#SQLRF52348) is a bit vague but doesn't indicate this is expected to be a problem:

> For compound queries containing set operators `UNION`, `INTERSECT`, `MINUS`, or `UNION ALL`, the `ORDER BY` clause must specify positions or aliases rather than explicit expressions. Also, the `ORDER BY` clause can appear only in the last component query. The `ORDER BY` clause orders all rows returned by the entire compound query.

You are aliasing your expression and using that, and it doesn't say you have to alias particular components (although of course it doesn't say you *don't* have to either).

The behaviour seems inconsistent with the alias being valid for the final projection, and the usual rule about the alias only being valid in the order by clause - this seems to be falling down somewhere in between.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the *OTN thread*, someone also came to the conclusion that *"'interestingly' it seems to require the the first and penultimate set of columns are aliased"*. I'll accept this as an answer to my question *"Is this a (known?) bug in the Oracle SQL parser"*

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't answer why you are getting inconsistent behavior from your current query, but in Oracle you can easily rewrite as the following (which should never fail with an invalid identifier error):

```
with t(x) as (
  select 'A' from dual
  union all
  select 'B' from dual
  union all
  select 'C' from dual
)
select * from t
order by x asc
```

With the added bonus that you only specify the column alias (x) once.