# group by and union in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I would like to union 2 queries but facing an error in oracle.

```
select count(*) as faultCount,
       COMP_IDENTIFIER 
from CORDYS_NCB_LOG 
where AUDIT_CONTEXT='FAULT' 
union 
select count(*) as responseCount,
       COMP_IDENTIFIER 
from CORDYS_NCB_LOG 
where AUDIT_CONTEXT='RESPONSE' 
group by COMP_IDENTIFIER  
order by responseCount;
```

Two queries run perfectly individually.but when using union,it says ORA-00904: "RESPONSECOUNT": invalid identifier

Comment: You are creating a resulset with a column with the count. You are defining 2 names for the same column. There is a correct answer, I'm just wondering if you want a single column or 2 columns.

Comment: i need 2 columns faultCount,responseCount

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The error you've run into

In Oracle, it's best to always name each column in each `UNION` subquery the same way. In your case, the following should work:

```
select count(*) as theCount,
       COMP_IDENTIFIER 
from CORDYS_NCB_LOG 
where AUDIT_CONTEXT='FAULT' 
group by COMP_IDENTIFIER -- don't forget this
union 
select count(*) as theCount,
       COMP_IDENTIFIER 
from CORDYS_NCB_LOG 
where AUDIT_CONTEXT='RESPONSE' 
group by COMP_IDENTIFIER  
order by theCount;
```

See also:

[Curious issue with Oracle UNION and ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25387951/521799)

A good workaround is, of course, to use indexed column references as suggested by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30712380/521799)

#### The query you really wanted

From your comments, however, I suspect you wanted to write an entirely different query, namely:

```
select count(case AUDIT_CONTEXT when 'FAULT'    then 1 end) as faultCount,
       count(case AUDIT_CONTEXT when 'RESPONSE' then 1 end) as responseCount,
       COMP_IDENTIFIER 
from CORDYS_NCB_LOG 
where AUDIT_CONTEXT in ('FAULT', 'RESPONSE')
group by COMP_IDENTIFIER  
order by responseCount;
```

Comment: It says ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: Thank you.It works.But is there a way to enhance it.It takes more than 10 seconds to retrieve which is not acceptable in case.

Comment: @user1650864: You should probably have an index: `CREATE INDEX my_index ON CORDYS_NCB_LOG(COMP_IDENTIFIER, AUDIT_CONTEXT)`

Comment: Still it takes 16 seconds !

Comment: Oh, perhaps, an additional `AUDIT_CONTEXT in ('FAULT', 'RESPONSE')` predicate might do the trick...

Answer (score 3):

The column names of a union are determined by the **first** query. So your first column is actually named `FAULTCOUNT`.

But the easiest way to sort the result of a union is to use the column index:

```
select ...
union 
select ...
order by 1;
```

You most probably also want to use `UNION ALL` which avoids removing duplicates between the two queries and is faster than a plain `UNION`

Comment: *"The column names of a union are determined by the first query"* - In fact, that's not entirely correct (for Oracle). It may well be that there is no available column name in `ORDER BY`. [This might just be a bug, though](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25387951/521799)

Comment: I need the resultset columns to be faultCount,responseCount,COMP_IDENTIFIER

Comment: Then you don't want a UNION. UNION says build one data set with the data from the second query tacked onto the end of the data set from the first query - and line up the columns. JOINs are for putting together two queries onto the same row.

Comment: @user1650864 The union only has two columns. And *one* column can only have *one* name. You can't name the first column `FAULTCOUNT` **and** `COMP_IDENTIFIER` at the same time.

Comment: hi,Can you post the query u r trying to explian

Comment: @user1650864: I'm trying to explain _your_ query.

Answer (score 0):

In Union or Union all query column names are determined by the first query column name.

In your query replace "order by responseCount" with "order by faultCount.