# Oracle 12c - Ambiguous column in Insert Into Select Query, ORA-00918

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, oracle12c, ora-00918

I am trying to execute multiple insert with single statement to achieve this I am using Insert into select statement. But I am facing when two columns have same value in insert. Error message that I am getting is **`ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`**.

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO sample (
    HOST,
    TOTAL_PING,
    TOTAL_UNAVAILABLE_PING
)

SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT 'FR3158-73-1',
    82,
    82
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'FR3158-76-2',
    80,
    10
    FROM DUAL
)
```

Issue is there in first select statement where two values are 82 and 82, if I change one value to something works. I don't know how to make this work even if column values are same.

**--- Updates ---**

**Table Definition**

```
CREATE TABLE sample
(
  ID                      NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  HOST                    VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
  TOTAL_PING              INTEGER,
  TOTAL_UNAVAILABLE_PING  INTEGER,
  ADDED_ON                TIMESTAMP(6)          DEFAULT systimestamp
);
```

Comment: Can you include the table definition for `sample` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Question updated, I have added table definition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case you don't need the subquery - as @Littlefoot showed. But if you did, with a more complicated scenario, you can avoid the error by aliasing the column expressions in the subquery:

```
INSERT INTO sample (
    HOST,
    TOTAL_PING,
    TOTAL_UNAVAILABLE_PING
)

SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT 'FR3158-73-1' as host,
    82 as total_ping,
    82 as total_unavailable_ping 
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'FR3158-76-2',
    80,
    10
    FROM DUAL
)
/

2 rows inserted.
```

---

The problem is that the subquery on its own gets implied column aliases, derived from the values in the first branch of the query:

```
SELECT 'FR3158-73-1',
82,
82 
FROM DUAL
UNION ALL

SELECT 'FR3158-76-2',
80,
10
FROM DUAL

'FR3158-73-         82         82
----------- ---------- ----------
FR3158-73-1         82         82
FR3158-76-2         80         10
```

The second and third columns are both called `"82"`, which is the ambiguity the ORA-00918 is complaining about, from the outer `select`. If you add aliases that goes away:

```
SELECT 'FR3158-73-1' as host,
82 as total_ping,
82 as total_unavailable_ping 
FROM DUAL
UNION ALL

SELECT 'FR3158-76-2',
80,
10
FROM DUAL

HOST        TOTAL_PING TOTAL_UNAVAILABLE_PING
----------- ---------- ----------------------
FR3158-73-1         82                     82
FR3158-76-2         80                     10
```

so the outer query is no longer confused. Note that you only need the aliases in the first branch of the union ([usually, anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25390187/266304)) - it doesn't hurt to have them in all branches, they'll just be ignored, but it saves a bit of typing if you're creating this manually. The actual alias names also don't matter in this case, they just have to be unique; specifically, they don't have to match the columns you're inserting into - but it makes it easier to follow if they do.

If you do it as @Littlefoot showed you don't have the intermediate result set `select`, so the derived names don't need to be evaluated (if they can be said to exist at all), so the ambiguity is not seen - it's purely positional.

Comment: Thanks Alex.. You have explained complete scenario in detail.. Upvote :)

Comment: Thanks for explaining this error. Very annoying, adding to the list of oracle workarounds to things that just work in t-SQL.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `select * from` ( (and trailing `)`).

```
INSERT INTO sample (HOST, TOTAL_PING, TOTAL_UNAVAILABLE_PING)
   SELECT 'FR3158-73-1', 82, 82 FROM DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'FR3158-76-2', 80, 10 FROM DUAL
```

---

**[EDIT, after a comment that it still doesn't work]**

Well, it *works*, at least in my 11gXE:

```
SQL> select * From v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> CREATE TABLE sample
  2  (
  3    ID                      NUMBER,
  4    HOST                    VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
  5    TOTAL_PING              INTEGER,
  6    TOTAL_UNAVAILABLE_PING  INTEGER,
  7    ADDED_ON                TIMESTAMP(6)          DEFAULT systimestamp
  8  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO sample (HOST, TOTAL_PING, TOTAL_UNAVAILABLE_PING)
  2     SELECT 'FR3158-73-1', 82, 82 FROM DUAL
  3             UNION ALL
  4             SELECT 'FR3158-76-2', 80, 10 FROM DUAL;

2 rows created.
```

No error on 12c either:

```
SQL> select * from v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER                                                                               CON_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production              0

SQL> CREATE TABLE sample
  2  (
  3    ID                      NUMBER,
  4    HOST                    VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
  5    TOTAL_PING              INTEGER,
  6    TOTAL_UNAVAILABLE_PING  INTEGER,
  7    ADDED_ON                TIMESTAMP(6)          DEFAULT systimestamp
  8  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO sample (HOST, TOTAL_PING, TOTAL_UNAVAILABLE_PING)
  2     SELECT 'FR3158-73-1', 82, 82 FROM DUAL
  3             UNION ALL
  4             SELECT 'FR3158-76-2', 80, 10 FROM DUAL;

2 rows created.

SQL>
```

Now, please, prove that it doesn't work on your database.

Comment: Nice one +1.  Do you know of some way to fix the exact code the OP is using?

Comment: Alex did that in his answer, @Tim.

Comment: Ummm .. what is "it", that is showing the same error?

Comment: Your query is showing same error that has been mentioned in my question.

Comment: I edited my answer by adding examples on live databases, 11gXE and 12cR2 - no error on either of them.

Comment: [Error] Execution (122: 8): ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined, My DB version `Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production`

Comment: Could you copy/past your SQL*Plus session by editing the original question? Don't do that as a comment, it is unreadable. I'd like to see both CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements. Basically, exactly as you see in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to name columns:

```
    INSERT INTO sample (HOST, TOTAL_PING, TOTAL_UNAVAILABLE_PING)
       SELECT 'FR3158-73-1' as host, 82 as total_ping, 82 as total_UNAVAILABLE_PING FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL
       SELECT 'FR3158-76-2' as host, 80 as total_ping, 10 as total_UNAVAILABLE_PING FROM DUAL
;
```

But better way is:

```
    INSERT INTO sample (HOST, TOTAL_PING, TOTAL_UNAVAILABLE_PING) values ('FR3158-73-1',82,82);
    INSERT INTO sample (HOST, TOTAL_PING, TOTAL_UNAVAILABLE_PING) values ('FR3158-76-2',80,10);
```

you avoid subquery.
If you have lots of data to insert into the database consider SQL*Loader and loading from text file.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-concepts.html#GUID-DD843EE2-1FAB-4E72-A115-21D97A501ECC